# Can I move the variables of a neural network from output to input?

Tags: neural-networks

Supposed I try to train an artificial neural network (ANN) function f1(x1,x2) = y1,y2, which uses 2 inputs and give 2 outputs.

Then is it logical / correct / workable to change the objective fn to f2(x1,x2,y1) = y2?

Can I use this to get the correct prediction? The reason why I am doing this is because I am trying to do some constraint optimization. The optimization library Hyperopt, allows input constraint e.g. 10 < x1 < 20. However, it doesn't allow output constraint e.g. y1 > 20. If I change my objective fn to that of f2, I will be able to get max y2 which satisfies my x1, x2 and y1 constraints.

Comment: Your NN outputs y1 based on your input x1 and x2, so how do you plan to input y1 at each iteration since it'll change wrt weights?

Comment: I am thinking that f1 can be a quadratic, cubic of higher function. Hence, for the same x1,x2, it can give 2 or more sets of y1 and y2. So for e.g., f(1,2) = (3,4) or (5,6). So f(1,2,3) should give (4) and f(1,2,5) should give (6). Does it make sense?